# Trouble with SCSS extending descendent selector

Tags: sass

I have a situation where I am attempting to `@extend` a descendant selector, but I am getting an error. Sample is shown below.

```
#font {
    .link{
        font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', 'Open Sans', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        ... some other stuff..
    }
}


a, .link {
    @extend #font > .link;
    @extend #state > .link;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, the selector for the first set of code is actually `#font .link`, not `#font > .link`.

Second, `@extend` can only extend simple selectors (`tag`, `.class`, `#id`, `%silentclass`, `tag.class`, `tag#id`, `tag%silentclass`, etc.), not nested selectors.  The error if you try to do so actually tells you this:

> Can't extend #font .link: can't extend nested selectors